# Fractional ideal of a Dedekind domain A is a projective module

Tags: projective-module, dedekind-domain

It can be known that any fractional ideal $\alpha$ of A can be generated by two elements, and is that enough to construct a reverse of the quotient map from $A^2$ to $\alpha$? And by the way, I wonder whether Dedekind domain is a UFD, and does g.c.d of two elements makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

A Dedekind domain is not necessarily a U.F.D. If it is, it actually is a P.I.D. For fractional ideals, a theorem asserts that, over a Dedekind domain, any finitely generated torsion-free module is projective.

Comment: @wangpengxin: Yes. *Stark-Heegner*'s theorem  gives the list of the $9$ negative integers $d$ such that the ring of integers of $\mathbf Q[\sqrt d]$ is principal. $-5$ is not in this list, and indeed $6$ has the factorisations $6=2\cdot 3=(1+i\sqrt 5)'1-i\sqrt 5)$. Note that no factor of the first factorisation is associated to a factor of the second factorisation, because the norms are different.